# On the capacity for equations of motion to be contained in field equations

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, geodesics, non-linear-systems

I've heard that the equation of geodesic motion can be derived from the vacuum Einstein field equations, although there appears to be some debate about how rigorously this can be proved, due to a point particle technically being a gravitational singularity and so forth.  But I was wondering, does this feature of a theory inherently require the field equations to be nonlinear?  Or is it conceivable that a linear theory such as Maxwell's equations could permit the derivation of the motion equations strictly from the field equations?